# How to assert values on a page opened by a link on another page?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, python

A link on page 1 opens a new page "receipt page".  It contains only text values.  I need to assert or verify values on the receipt page to ensure that this is the correct receipt.

After executing the line

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Print Order!").click() #this what navigates the receipt page
```

the following tags are returned and must be validated:

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px dashed black;">
<span>Receipt No: 197</span>
<span style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:lighter;margin-left:130px;">16/10/2012 -04:10 pm </span>
<br>
<span>Customer Name: 123</span>
<br>
<span>Cashier Name: engy</span>
<br>
<br>
<table width="100%" style="font-size:smaller; border-bottom:1px dotted black;text-align:center;">
<br>
<span>Total Cost: 5700</span>
```

Comment: I think I understand the problem you are trying to solve, but what is your question?

Comment: now i succeeded to make a test case that do some actions and the last action is to generate a receipt page to be printed. my question is i need to verify text on that page to ensure that it's the correct receipt

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this?  You don't mention any blocking issues, or give a description of what sort of failure is occurring.  Are you asking what should you verify on the receipt page, or how to do it?

Comment: no, i'm asking what code to write to verify a text on a page with "about:blank" URL how to make selenium webdriver point to that new page.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the code would be:

`driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());`

This will switch to the newly opened window and then you would treat it just like any other page.  To switch back would be:

`driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();`